# Polymer is a framework instead of a library. How can I modularly use web components?

Tags: javascript, html, polymer, web-component

The idea of web components is to modularize the web regardless of what framework you use.

The Polymer project promise the possibility to create web components, not to be a framework, so it should be possible to use it with any framework. More than that, I should be able to just download the elements from the [element catalog](https://elements.polymer-project.org/) and use it without the polymer library, just with the webcomponents.js.

I recognize that this is an ongoing project and most of browser's vendors are still developing the web components requirements, but what I'm concluding so far is that the Polymer is becoming a new framework as I cannot use their elements without the Polymer library and the use with framework as Angular 2 is not yet working well.

Is that a way to use web components in a real modular way without all the boilerplate that the Polymer suggest?

Comment: Of course there is by using native API's and writing your own library. Other than that this question is far too broad to expect a reasonable answer

Comment: further reading about web components at: http://webcomponents.org/

Comment: You might want to ask about your Angular problem in a separate question. I have not tried, but any Web Components should work just fine with Angular 2. Polymer should be no exception.

Answer (score 6):

### TL;DR;

Polymer does not break the modularity merely by the fact that it's required to use Web Components built with it. It is just a library, albeit opinionated, used to implement custom elements.

These elements are however still independent modules. All of Polymer stuff should be hidden inside a component and not interfere with the outside.

### Long read

> The idea of web components is to modularize the web regardless of what framework you use

In a sense, yes. Though Web Components target to modularize the DOM really. For general modularization, there are ES6 modules IMO.

> The Polymer project promise the possibility to create web components, not to be a framework, so it should be possible to use it with any framework.

I'm not sure what you expect from Polymer and Web Components in general. The modularity of Web Components come from the fact that when used, they are just an ordinary part of the DOM tree. Any existing library can work with that. Any Web Component is just a HTML element and exposes a uniform interface: **attributes and events**. What Polymer does is add some niceties on top of that so that you can enjoy [data-binding](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding.html), [simpler custom element declarations](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/registering-elements.html), [simpler events API](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/events.html), [styling polyfill](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/styling.html), [shady DOM](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/articles/shadydom.html) and more.

It's a dependency like any other and should not stop you from using Polymer (or [Bosonic](http://bosonic.github.io/), or [x-tag](http://x-tag.github.io/), or [basic-web-components](https://github.com/basic-web-components)) with any other web framework.

> More than that, I should be able to just download the elements from the element catalog and use it **without the polymer library**, just with the webcomponents.js.

Where did you read that? Also, is it a problem that `polymer.html` is required for the components to work? You may get the same with other Web Components libraries.

> I recognize that this is an ongoing project and most of browser's vendors are still developing the web components requirements.

I believe there is a need of clarification. The vendors implement the Web Components spec and where it isn't ready, webcomponents.js fill in the blanks. Just as I write above however, Polymer is a little bit more, because it gives you more than pure specs.

> Is that a way to use web components in a real modular way without all the boilerplate that the Polymer suggest?

Not sure what is the bolierplate that you refer to, but yes, you can write Web Components in [plain javascript](https://teamgaslight.com/blog/roll-your-own-html5-web-components-with-vanilla-js) (or in a [minimal dependencies fashion](https://github.com/pemrouz/vanilla#vanilla)) but you will lose some of the sugar that Web Components give you. It is just like arguing that one shouldn't use jQuery, because all that it does can be done without it.